# UITableViewCell Editing Minus Sign Frame and swiping left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`UITableViewCell` Editing Minus Sign Frame and swiping left shows `More`option with red background. When I swipe left again, cell content appears over `More` like in an image below.

[image]

Any suggestions so that it don't appear over `More`